# Getting ENOTFOUND error while connecting Aurora MySQL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora

I have Lambda function which is connecting to Aurora MySQL database. But sometimes with no reason, I'm getting the error below;

`getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND {hostname}","errno":"ENOTFOUND","code":"ENOTFOUND","syscall":"getaddrinfo","hostname":{hostname} at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] dns.js:66:26`

- I don't have any problem with the clusters when the error happening. No spikes, no overload nothing. It's happening rarely (Maybe one time after 300~ invocation).
- The nslookup is working fine, it shows no problem with RDS instances and DNS resolution.
- I'm only using lambda for MySQL selects.

I know I can use retry strategy when i get this error but i want to understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem on the AWS side. A while ago, they've mentioned they were taking many messages according to this problem. They are continuously working on this problem and after 1 year it reduced dramatically. So I'm closing this question.